# Timing for loop changes when using other functions in the computer Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a pulsing animation in this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/upBdw/8/

When you use it on its own, it works just fine. The problem I'm having is when I start browsing the web, open iTunes or whatever else you would do while that window is still open, the timings of the pulses start to fluctuate.

The function for the pulses is this:

```
function fadeItIn() {

    window.setInterval(function(){

        // Fade Ins
        $('#child4,#child4C').fadeIn(175);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child3,#child3C').fadeIn(175);
        }, 175);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child2,#child2C').fadeIn(175);
        }, 350);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child1,#child1C').fadeIn(175);
        }, 525);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child,#childC').fadeIn(175);
        }, 700);

        // Fade Outs
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child,#childC').fadeOut(175);
        }, 875);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child1,#child1C').fadeOut(175);
        }, 1050);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child2,#child2C').fadeOut(175);
        }, 1225);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child3,#child3C').fadeOut(175);
        }, 1400);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#child4,#child4C').fadeOut(175);
        }, 1575);  

    }, 3000);   
};
```

I feel like the issue is happening during the 3 second interval within the function. I need the pulses to repeat, so I need it in there.

What do you all think is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is put one set timeout inside another one.

Right now you have 
setTimeout(, time);
setTImeout(, time*2);
setTImeout(, time*3);

Maybe if you change this to:
setTimeout(... setTimeout(... setTimeout(...,time), time), time);

So this will ensure order of execution. First one will always execution.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Put like all 3 pulses in the same function and order them so that they go off correctly the first time and repeat that main function. That will make it so that the timings never get off. Right?

Comment: What I mean is first timeout function will do its thing and then call second timeout (from the first timeout function). The second timeout function will do its thing and then call third set timeout. Third will do its thing and then call fourth and so on.

Something like 

setTimeout(functionA(){//do stuff. 
                setTimeout(functionB(){
                        /// do stuff 
                        setTimout(functionC(){
                        //do stuff
                        },time)
                   ,time)
, time)

Comment: I just did that and it didnt fix my issue.

Comment: I think what is going on is the browser is trying to do too much at once and failing. Maybe the only way to fix it is to improve the efficiency of the code.